# Asp.net mvc 4 how to use WebSecurity.createUserAndAccount with custom field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with I create a custom field in `UserProfile` table.like

```
public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        public int? UserDetailId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }


        public UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }


    }

   public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }

    }

     public class UserDetail 
     {
         public int Id{get;set;}
         public string FirstName{get;set;}    
         public string LastName{get;set;} 
     }
```

And I also added `UserDetail` to `DbContext` class

```
  public DbSet<UserDetail> UserDetails{get;set;}
```

The Problem is when I use

```
Web  WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, 
                        new { UserDetail = new UserDetail ()
                        }, false);
```

It always comes up with some error like :No mapping exists from object type...
But If I define a simple type (like `string`, `int`) instead of `UserDetail`, it works fine.

Anyone can help me solve this problem? Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem to this and got it work by:

combine UserDetail and UserProfile to something along this line:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{get;set;}    
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

update your [HttpPost] Register

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, 
   propertyValues: new { FirstName= model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName}, false);
```

don't forget to add the new fields into your RegisterModel as needed

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    ....
    public string FirstName{get;set;}    
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

hope this works for you

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking to do this.

**UserDetail**

```
public class UserDetail 
 {
     //This is property mapping, UserId will be the same as the Membership UserId and UserProfile UserId
     [Key]
     [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
     [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
     public int UserId { get; set; }

     public string FirstName{get;set;}    
     public string LastName{get;set;}

     public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; } 
 }
```

**RegisterModel**

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName{get;set;}

    [Required]   
    public string LastName{get;set;}
 }
```

**Register Action**

```
//
    // GET: /Account/Register

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var db = new UsersContext();
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
               var userProfile = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, null, false);

                //var userProfile= db.UserProfile.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == model.UserName);

                if (userProfile!= null) //This way Userdetail is only created if UserProfile exists so that it can retrieve the foreign key
                {
                    var userDetail = new UserDetail
                                           {
                                               UserProfile = userProfile,
                                               FirstName = model.FirstName,
                                               LastName = model.LastName
                                           };                                                

                    db.UserDetails.Add(userDetail);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }                    
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Edit**

Depending on how you have set up your Context and repositories, you will need something like below for each of your POCO classes

```
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    IQueryable<UserProfile> IDataSource.UserProfiles
    {
        get { return UserProfiles; }
    }
```

In addition to SimpleMembership tables, you will need to add the following to your context for `many-to-many` between `Membership and Roles`

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Membership>()
          .HasMany<Role>(r => r.Roles)
          .WithMany(u => u.Members)
          .Map(m =>
          {
              m.ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles");
              m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
              m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
          });
    }
```

Comment: I'm testing out your code, but it says my context does not contain a definition for UserProfile or for UserDetails ! Are we suppose to add something to our db context? I'm stuck with this too!

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get past the problem I was having, however I am getting `null` on this line `var userProfile = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == model.UserName);` any reason for this? When I check Db, the Username has been created, but the UserDetails table is empty, obviously because that line returns null.

Comment: @Ciwan Comment that line out and add `var userProfile = ` in front of `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount()` like i have done now in the answer.